# How to convert IBM IOCA (G4 MMR-Modified Modified READ) image (ImageData-Triplet) as tiff or pdf or

Tags: java, pdfbox

I was able to open MO: DCA file using library https://github.com/yan74/afplib and I was successful getting hands on the Image Triplets (IOCA) but I don't know to how convert the image into tiff or pdf or any.

I'm currently trying to view the image using itext5, pdfbox.
Any Java sample code will help.

The properties of the IOCA Image file I was able get using afplib SDFHelper.ipds2sdf and Triplets (BeginSegment, BeginImage,ImageSizeImpl,IDESizeImpl,ImageLUTID, ImageEncodingImpl, ImageData)

```
BeginSegment.getSEGNAME() :null
BeginImage.getOBJTYPE() :255(IOCA)
ImageSizeImpl.getVRESOL :2000, (200 dpi)
ImageSizeImpl.getVSIZE :5000 (height)
ImageSizeImpl.getHRESOL :2000 (200 dpi)
ImageSizeImpl.getHSIZE :1196 (width)
ImageSizeImpl.getUNITBASE :0
IDESizeImpl.iDESizeImpl :1
ImageLUTID.ImageLUTID : 0
ImageEncodingImpl.getBITORDR :null
ImageEncodingImpl.getCOMPRID :ConstG4MMR (G4 MMR-Modified Modified READ)
ImageEncodingImpl.getRECID :1 (RECID Algo)
ImageData.getDATA() - Is confidential, I don't have the test data.
```

I'm currently trying to view the image using itext5, pdfbox.
Any java sample code will help.

Comment: I was able to decompress the Binary data and now I have the G4 MMR decompressed data. Can anyone please tell me how to construct a B/W Image from Group 4 decompressed byte[] or any sample code, it would be so helpful.

Java Class : https://github.com/ESCRIBA/lenient-pdf-compare/blob/4dcedec705b70328fa78935e0e2f95a94a89ef8c/src/com/sun/pdfview/decode/CCITTFaxDecoder.java

Method used: public synchronized void decodeT6(byte[] buffer, byte[] compData,int startX, int height)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could create a TYPE_BINARY BufferedImage with this size, and then assign the b/w colors with setRGB. You'd need to find out whether the b/w values are stored as bits or as bytes.